# Overwriting when using Map.putAll()

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having some difficulty when using Map.putAll(). Instead of updating / adding particular records to my main map, it is overwriting the entries:

```
  ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>>();
```

The three separate maps are generated as below:

```
   ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>> businessCardCache = buildBusinesscardCacheValues(connection, getBusinessCards);
   ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>> personalCardCache = buildPersonalcardCacheValues(connection, getPersonalCards);
   ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>> socialCardCache = buildSocialcardCacheValues(connection, getSocialCard);
   cache.putAll(businessCardCache);
   cache.putAll(personalCardCache);
   cache.putAll(socialCardCache);
```

What should happen is user ben for example should be the key and he should have a business a personal and a social card. What in fact happens is he only ends up with a socialCard as I assume it is the last to run and therefore overwrites the previous.

How should I approach modifying this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems right. What do you expect? How is the `Map` supposed to know how you want to merge values? Any `put` operation replaces the mapping if present. If using Java 8 you can use `merge`. Otherwise you will need custom logic.

Comment: `putAll` essentially calls `put` for every entry. Javadocs for put: `Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.** (A map m is said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k) would return true.)`. Thus this is expected behavior -- entries will be overriden.

Comment: You have records with same key comming from your source maps, this wont even work with a simple `Map#put(key, value)`, you need to check before the put if a value with a given key is present and implement a merge strategy.

Comment: It seems like perhaps you want to have a Map of a List of Cards, grab the list passing the name Ben to the map and add to the list.

Comment: Have you considered using a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)?

Comment: Will creating an inner cache class which stores the User string and all the business,personal,social cache be suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Your current initialization of `cache` would cause `cache.putAll(personalCardCache);` to replace the values added by `cache.putAll(businessCardCache);` for keys that appear in both maps.

If you want `cache` to contain all the cards of each user (taken from all 3 input maps), you should initialize it in a different way :

```
for (String key : businessCardCache.keySet()) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card> cards = null;
    if (cache.containsKey(key) {
        cards = cache.get(key);
    } else {
        cards = new ConcurrentHashMap<CardType, Card>();
    }
    cards.putAll (businessCardCache.get(key));
}
```

Then you do the same for the other 2 maps.